# Can't check string with foreach

Tags: php

I have got this php array

```
$Topic=[
    '50 Cent' => '50cent.jpg Rap',
    'Adam Levine' => 'adam.jpg Rock',
    'Android' => 'android.jpg Operating System',
];
```

and this foreach code

```
    <?php foreach ($Topic as $key => $value):
    $type=substr($value,strpos($value,' ')); 
    $value=explode(' ',$value);?>
        <?php if (strcmp($type,'Rap')==0): ?>
            <div class="topic_d">
                <img src="topics/<?php echo $value[0]?>" class="topic_img"> 
            </div>      
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

My goal here is to print all topics in array that have got type 'Rap'.But i can't do that,even though when i print `type` it returns Rap/

Comment: You have created a new array with explode, you should try something like:
`if (strpos($value, 'Rap') !== false) {
    // true -> do what you need
}`
and get rid of explode part...

Comment: Add 1 to `strpos()` to skip over the space

Comment: `strcmp($type, 'Rap') == 0` is the same as `$type == 'Rap'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add trim to compare type with 'Rap'

```
if (strcmp(trim($type),'Rap')==0)
```

or to

```
$type=trim(substr($value,strpos($value,' ')));
```

Because type is not 'Rap' but ' Rap'

Comment: Thanks for thy answer!

Answer (score 0):

You may also go for a regex alternative :

```
<?php
    $Topic=[
        '50 Cent'       => '50cent.jpg Rap',
        'Adam Levine'   => 'adam.jpg Rock',
        'Android'       => 'android.jpg Operating System',
    ];

    $regex_topic = '/^[a-z0-9.]+\s([a-z\s]+)$/gi';
?>

<?php foreach( $Topic as $topic_key => $topic_value ): ?>
    <?php
        $match = '';
        preg_match($regex_topic, $topic_value, $topic);
    ?>

    <?php if( isset($match[1]) && $match[1] == 'Rap' ): ?>
        <div class="topic_d">
            <img src="topics/<?php echo $value[0]?>" class="topic_img"> 
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The regex can be read like :

1. `[a-z0-9.]+\s` is your .jpg part, so we catch a bunch of character followed by a space
2. `[a-z\s]+` is your topic, a combination of characters and spaces
3. grouping them with parenthesis `([a-z\s]+)` allow you to catch them
4. To catch a group, you need to pass an additionnal variable by reference in `preg_match($regex, $string, $match)`, where `$match[0]` contains the entired catched string according the regex and `$match[1], $match[2], ... $match[n]` are your groups [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)